# Как работает макрос CHECK в исходниках chromium?

Tags: c++, chromium

Я начал разбираться в исходниках chromium-a в свободное время и наткнулся на один момент, осмыслить который не могу уже несколько месяцев.

У них есть макрос [CHECK](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:base/check.h;l=120), которым они везде пользуются.
Он раскрывается в такую вещь (**немного упростил**, чтобы не городить тут бесчисленное множество макросов):

```
#define CHECK(condition)                                                     \
  LAZY_CHECK_STREAM(                                                         \
      CheckError::Check(__FILE__, __LINE__, #condition).stream(),            \
      !condition)
```

---

[LAZY_CHECK_STREAM](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:base/check.h;l=55) представляет из себя слудующее:

```
#define LAZY_CHECK_STREAM(stream, condition) \
  !(condition) ? (void)0 : ::logging::VoidifyStream() & (stream)
```

- если условие верное, то void(0), т.е. ничего
- если условие ложное, то передает поток в `VoidifyStream`

---

Функция [CheckError::Check](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:base/check.h;l=70):

```
class CheckError {
 public:
  static CheckError Check(const char* file,
                         int line,
                         const char* condition) {
    CheckError check_error(new LogMessage(file, line, LOGGING_FATAL));
    check_error.stream() << "Check failed: " << condition << ". ";
    return check_error;
  }

 private:
  explicit CheckError(LogMessage* log_message);

  LogMessage* log_message_;
};
```

Просто помещает в поток информацию об ошибке вида `[INFO:test.cpp(96)] ...`

---

И последний класс [VoidifyStream](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:base/check.h;l=44) :

```
class VoidifyStream {
 public:
  VoidifyStream() = default;
  explicit VoidifyStream(bool ignored) {}

  // This operator has lower precedence than << but higher than ?:
  void operator&(std::ostream&) {}
};
```

Не могу назвать это иначе, как гаситель потока. Любой поток, который передается в него с помощью `operator&` превращается в `void`

---

Теперь я объясню, как я вижу применение макроса `CHECK`

Допустим, есть какая-то функция, где я хочу проверить аргумент на неравенство нулю

```
void foo(int not_null) {
  CHECK(not_null != 0);
  // А можно и так
  // CHECK(not_null != 0) << "Not null was 0. Alarm!";
}
```

Все прекрасно работает, но **зачем нужно было добавлять `ostream` в класс**, чтобы хранить информацию об ошибке, если в конечном итоге, при любом варианте, `VoidifyStream` гасит этот поток?

Получается, что есть макросс `CHECK`, который хранит строку об ошибке, но использовать ее никак не получится. Например хоть так:

```
void foo(int not_null) {
  std::cout << CHECK(not_null != 0) << "Not null was 0. Alarm!"; // Выведет: 0
}
```

**Что в работе макроса я неправильно понимаю?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`VoidifyStream` ни как не влияет на то что поток делает или печатает; он нужен просто чтобы привести поток к типу `void`, чтобы согласовать возвращаемые типы оператора `?:`.

Такое шаманство, вместо более тривиального варианта:

```
!(condition) ? (void)0 : (void)(stream)
```

здесь используется чтобы можно было направлять в тот же самый поток дополнительную информацию, [как здесь](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:sandbox/linux/syscall_broker/broker_file_permission.cc;l=250;drc=c7ab653f206758e37caa10927e4c7e393d9c329e;bpv=0;bpt=1):

```
CHECK(path_.length() > 0) << GetErrorMessageForTests();
```

В этом случае макрос раскрывается во что-то типа:

```
!(path_.length() > 0) ? 
 (void)0 : 
 ::logging::VoidifyStream() &  
       CheckError::Check(/*...*/).stream() << GetErrorMessageForTests();
```

Оператор `&` [специально](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:base/check.h;l=49;bpv=0;bpt=1) так выбран, чтобы быть менее приоритетным, чем `<<`, но более приоритетным, чем `?:`. Так что вся активность связанная с потоком выполнится только если условие ложно, а `<< GetErrorMessageForTests()` из кода вызывающего макрос выполнится до «вызова» `VoidifyStream::operator&(std::ostream&)`.

---

В дальнейшем, при уничтожении временного объекта `CheckError` и, как следствие, `LogMessage` это сообщение будет передано подсистеме управления логированием (см. [`LogMessage::~LogMessage()`](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:base/logging.cc;l=593;drc=34bb6fac36999c3f41b77122ae52d242866496a5;bpv=0;bpt=1)), которая уже запишет его в какой-нибудь файл, выведет в консоль, подошьёт к отчёту об ошибке или сделает что-то ещё, в зависимости от настроек.

Вероятно, чтобы увидеть его надо [включить логирование](https://www.chromium.org/for-testers/enable-logging).

Comment: Все равно не понимаю. В режиме дебага CHECH создает сообщение об ошибке, мы добавляем туда дополнительную информацию , и тут же этот поток становится void и его даже никак не вывести. Получается, что в режиме Release дополнительная информация не генерируется и программа сразу крашится. В режиме Debug информация об ошибке обнуляется, краша нет. Какой толк от этого макроса в дебаге тогда?

Comment: @AntonMitrochin, добавил в ответ…

Comment: Все! Наконец-то! Вот они куда запрятали вывод логов. Спасибо большое вам!