# Как вызвать немедленное падение программы при компиляции с помощью clang++?

Tags: c++

### Как вызвать немедленное падение программы при компиляции с помощью clang++?

```
#ifdef(MSVC_COMPILER)
  #define IMMEDIATE_CRASH() __debugbreak()
#elif(GNU_COMPILER)
  #define IMMEDIATE_CRASH() __builtin_trap()
#elif(CLANG_COMPILER)
  #define IMMEDIATE_CRASH() // как в этом случае?
#else
  #error ...
#endif
```

Только нужен хороший вариант, что-то типа `1/0` не подойдет.

Comment: Все что пришло в голову - через инструкции ассемблера что-то придумать

Comment: Падение программы может произойти только во время ее выполнения. Если нужна ошибка компиляции, то есть `static_assert`.

Comment: присоединяюсь к терминологическим нацикам выше… а по сути: `__builtin_trap()` не работает что ли?

Comment: @user7860670 речь о компиляции кода в clang, а не о падении во время компиляции.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не знаю откуда взят приведённый код, но судя по предыдущему [вашему вопросу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1374553/176217) речь, вероятно, о Chromium. Быстрый гуглинг вывел меня на такой [diff](https://codereview.chromium.org/1216123003/diff/1/Source/wtf/Assertions.h). Где как раз предлагается использовать тот же самый вызов `__builtin_trap()` при использовании clang. Более того, на [странице документации по clang](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html) есть разбор опции `-ftrap-function=[name]`, где как раз сказано про `__builtin_trap()`:

> LLVM code generator translates __builtin_trap() to a trap instruction if it is supported by the target ISA. Otherwise, the builtin is translated into a call to abort. If this option is set, then the code generator will always lower the builtin to a call to the specified function regardless of whether the target ISA has a trap instruction.